# how can I change font size on MKAnnotation title and subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotation

how can I change MKAnnotation title and subtitle this is my code

```
 Newclass *ann1 = [[Newclass alloc] init];
ann1.title = namef1;
ann1.subtitle = @"";
ann1.coordinate = place1.center;
[mapView addAnnotation: ann1];
```

I searched to use

```
UIFont *size = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
CGSize textsize = [ann1.title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:size}];
```

but Build this code it shown un used variable textsize

Comment: There is no built-in provision for changing the title / subtitle font of an annotation's callout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear distinction between a `MKAnnotation` and a `MKAnnotationView`. You won't be able to customize an object that subscribes to the MKAnnotationProtocol in such a way that you hope because the `MKAnnotation` protocol only asks objects to maintain variables to store information that will be later drawn by an `MKAnnotationView` object.

I recommend you write a custom `MKAnnotationView` subclass that contains the custom fonts, sizes & anything else applicable to how you'd like the annotation to look.

[This tutorial might help you out.](https://tlextrait.svbtle.com/displaying-custom-pins-on-mkmapview)

Comment: Has this answer helped you?