# Xcode mkpointannotation default font type and size

Tags: swift, xcode, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpointannotation

I am using various mkpointannotations and custom mkannotations in my map application.  I want all of them to have uniform text but I can't figure out what the default font is for mkpointannotation.  I have googled around and checked options click the mkpointannotation in Xcode to read it's documentation but couldn't find anything regarding its font type and size.

Does any one know what they are or a way for me to print out mkpointannotation attributes?  Thanks.

Comment: This might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37265755/1805608

Comment: Hi Harish.  Thats one of the links I used to create my custom mkannotation but I'm trying to find what the mkpointannotation default font attributes are so I can mimic it in my custom mkannotation.